# directoryentry.invoke("changepassword") the max password length

Tags: c#, .net

I've met a error when I try to update the password of the user from `Active Directory` by invoke method

`DirectoryEntry.Invoke("changepassword", object[]{oldPassword, newPassword})`

The new password is complex enough and can update the password successfully when the length of the new password is less than `63(include 63)`, but when the length of the new password is larger than `63`, one error happened. The error message is:

```
Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052D).
```

The code is:

```
public static void ChangePassword(DirectoryEntry user, string oldPassword, string newPassword)       
{              
    oldPassword = (oldPassword == null) ? string.Empty : oldPassword;
    newPassword = (newPassword == null) ? string.Empty : newPassword;
    if (oldPassword != newPassword)
    {
        user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword, newPassword });
    }
}
```

I don't know why it happened now, does anyone know that? thank you!

Comment: would please show code of change password.

Comment: I've added the code to the question, please have a check, thank you!

Comment: limit for password is 127. It's like if your password was in wide char ...

Comment: Are you sure the limit for password is 127? For when I invoke "SetPassword" to reset the password, it will success when the length of password is less than 256(include 256), but when the length of password is larger than 256, there also have this kind of exception happened.